# Creating a Line of Best Fit in R

Tags: r

[image]

Hi, I was wondering if anyone could help me on how to complete function in R as I am totally new to this computer programming. So apologies if this seems like a silly question to this audience.

So I am currently trying to add a line of best fit onto my scatter graph but I'm not quite understanging how to do this. I've tried many functions like "abline" and "lm" but I'm not sure if I am using the right ideas or whether I am putting incorrect numbers into the functions.

I have cleared the workspace and just left my graph and previous workings so that it looks neater.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Preferably, you can put your code into codeblocks on the question text. It's much easier to see what you're showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reproducible data example:

```
set.seed(2348907)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 2*(x+rnorm(100))
```

then this makes a linear model for the intercept and slope:

```
lmodel <- lm(y ~ x)
```

which now contains the intercept (`Intercept` term) and the slope (as the coefficient of the x variable in the model). Here is a summary of the model:

```
summary(lmodel)
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8412 -1.0767 -0.1808  1.2216  4.1540 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.0454     0.1851   0.245    0.807    
x             2.1087     0.1814  11.627   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.848 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5797,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5754 
F-statistic: 135.2 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

then make the plot using the `coef()` function to pull out the intercept and slope from the linear model:

```
plot(x,y)  # plots the points
abline(a=coef(lmodel)[1], b=coef(lmodel)[2])  # plots the line, a=intercept, b=slope
```

[image]

personally, I prefer `ggplot2` for such things, which would be like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x,y), method="lm", se=F)
```

[image]

Comment: not sure why people prefer ggplot so much. Those labels are sized too small and there's no title, so I'd have to go look up three more functions with multiple parameters just to make the plots easier to read. Also, the default gray grid isn't even pretty and it has no border. That's like 3 more commands/layers.

Comment: the label size is partly due to how I copied the image out. but, yeah, it's personal preference - for me, control over formatting and piping are 2 big bonuses. but it is a preference, and a rich subject of debate: http://varianceexplained.org/r/why-I-use-ggplot2/